# PostgreSQL select all views where current user can write queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

How cant I select all **views** where current user can write queries (write selects)

Is this select correct?

```
SELECT * 
FROM pg_views, pg_user 
WHERE has_table_privilege (current_user, schemaname||'.'|| viewname, 'select')
```